# Why isn't my GetProcessID function compiling in VS?

Tags: c++

so for some reason my GetProcessID function is working in one project (no errors when compiling the source) but recently I just started a new project and now I am getting the error

```
'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'
```

But why am I even getting this cannot convert from WCHAR to const char * error? If I hover over p32.szExeFile szExeFile is type CHAR [260] not WCHAR. Also, I went into property pages and selected Use Multi-Byte Character Set. Even if I change std::string processName parameter to

```
const char *processName
```

or

```
char *processName 

wchar_t *processName
```

I still get the same error.

So my question is this: Why is it that my GetProcessID function works in another project without any compilation errors but when I try to use this same function in a brand new project I get an error?

```
  DWORD GetProcessID(std::string processName)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            std::cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() (of processes)" << std::endl;
            std::cin.get();
            return 0;
        }

        if (!Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32))
        {
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
            std::cout << "The first entry of the process list wasn't copied to the buffer." << std::endl;
            std::cin.get();
            return 0;
        }

        while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32))
        {
            if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, processName.c_str()) == 0)
            {
                CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
                return pe32.th32ProcessID;
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        DWORD dwProcessID = NULL;
        while (dwProcessID == NULL)
        {
            dwProcessID = GetProcessID("proc.exe");
        }

        std::cout << "Found PID " << dwProcessID << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What @J.Doe is trying to tell you is to please make a [mre]. (Jon, try using `[mre]` in comments like yours instead of asking for "full" code. Believe me, you do not really want that, the MRE is optimal. )

Comment: The failing project is compiled as Unicode.  When you do that, strings in `PROCESSENTRY32` are defined as `WCHAR []` rather than `char []`.  One solution would be to explicitly code `PROCESSENTRY32A` (and `Process32FirstA` / `Process32NextA`), although Unicode strings are better able to represent non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Yunnosch *instead of asking for "full" code.* – Right, nobody wants that :D

Comment: I like the mix of `std::string` and `strcmp`.

Comment: @PaulSanders EDIT: Nvm. You're right. I went into configuration properties and noticed that when I changed the character set to multibyte it didn't apply to all configurations.

Comment: @kroosha No worries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 You're right, I added an answer.

Comment: @PaulSanders Excellent, thank you

Answer (score 4):

The failing project is compiled as Unicode. When you do that, strings in `PROCESSENTRY32` are defined as `WCHAR []` rather than `char []`.

One solution would be to explicitly code `PROCESSENTRY32A` (and `Process32FirstA` / `Process32NextA`), although Unicode strings are better able to represent non-ASCII characters.